# Can connect to Google Cloud SQL through a proxy, but can't once deployed

Tags: google-app-engine, sqlalchemy

As the title says, I managed to get my Cloud SQL instance all connected to my Flask App via SQLAlchemy using Google's Cloud proxy, but once I deploy the app, it can't connect.

I'm figuring it's an issue with the Database URI I'm providing (since the two connections require different URI's), but for the life of me, I cannot figure out what the string should be.

When connecting locally through the proxy, I have this in my code:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:MYPASSWORD@127.0.0.1:3307/inkdb?unix_socket=/cloudsql/MYPROJECTID:us-east1:MYDBINSATNCEID'
```

and I get it to connect and work fine.  Following the online documentation, I tried connecting to a number of different URI's, including:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://root@/inkdb?unix_socket=/cloudsql/MYPROJECTID:us-east1:MYDBINSATNCEID'
```

(I could try listing all the URI's I tried, but it would be a long list).

Is there something fundamental I'm missing?  I'm pretty sure I have included all my 3rd party packages as required, but I just can't get anything out of it.  I've looked all over the internet (with special attention to SE, of course), but nothing seems to work.

I'd appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the error message?

Comment: Sorry, I got wrapped in trying to figure out that I forgot about this thread.  It ended up being the case that the server's MySQLdb version was 1.3.5 but mine was 1.2.7, raising the error:

`ImportError: this is MySQLdb version (1, 3, 7, 'final', 1), but _mysql is version (1, 2, 5, 'final', 1)`

This was confusing because I has added the line to import the latest version of MySQLdb into my app.yaml, but it wasn't allowing me to update it past 1.2.5.  It ended up being that I accidently installed MySQLdb in my lib folder, and it was messing everything up.  I deleted it and everything works.

Comment: I'm also having this issue.
I don't think it's related to MySQLdb however...
Maybe configuration or something for me...